# MongoDB C# driver upserting nested document

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I have deeply embedded documents in MongoDB like so:

```
[
 {
  id : 1,
  stuff : [
           {
            id : 1,
            morestuff: [
                        {id : 1, text : "foo"},
                        {id : 2, text : "boo"}
                       ]
           },
           {
            id : 2,
            morestuff: [
                        {id : 1, text : "foo2"},
                        {id : 2, text : "boo2"}
                       ]
           } 
          ]
 }
]
```

My C# representation is like:

```
class CoreElement
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Stuff> stuff { get; set; }
}
class Stuff
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<MoreStuff> morestuff { get; set; }
}
class MoreStuff
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can have different situations:

1. CoreElement with given ID doesn't exist
2. Stuff with given ID is not on the list in CoreElement
3. MoreStuff is not on a list in Stuff in CoreElement

If I create an object like that:

```
CoreElement ce = new CoreElement();
ce.id = 1;
Stuff st = new Stuff();
st.id = 2;
MoreStuff ms = new MoreStuff();
ms.id = 17;
ms.text = "something";
st.morestuff.Add(ms);
ce.stuff.Add(st);
```

Is there a way to upsert it to my collection so it adds MoreStuff to the appropriate document if one already exists, or creates new document (CoreElement or Stuff) if one doesn't already exist?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the upsert with a `$push`?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/)

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array only if the value is not in the array already. If the value is in the array, $addToSet returns without modifying the array.

Something else you can do is to load your CoreElement and work with it in memory. You can add Suffs and MoreStuffs to the object checking for duplicates with C#. When you are finished with the object just save it, MongoDB will replace the object in the collection with your modified object.